# Object not callable in Python Abstraction

Tags: python, oop, abstraction, lld

Hi can someone tell me why the below code shows the error, I think this should run fine -

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
class DriveStrategy(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def drive_strategy(self):
        pass
    
class NormalDrive(DriveStrategy):
    def drive_strategy(self):
        print("Normal Drive")

class SpecialDrive(DriveStrategy):
    def drive_strategy(self):
        print("Special Drive")
        
        
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, drive: DriveStrategy):
        self.drive = drive
    
    def drive(self):
        self.drive.drive_strategy()

class SUV(Vehicle):
    def just_a_method(self):
        print("from SUV")

class PassengerBus(Vehicle):
    def bus_method(self):
        print("From Bus")

safari = SUV(SpecialDrive())
safari.drive()
```

It shows
`'SpecialDrive' object is not callable`

Expecting that to print "Special Drive".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of this code is in `Class Vehicle`, the variable name `self.drvie` is same with the function `drive()`.
To solve this problem, you just need to use another name for the function. There is an  example:

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, drive: DriveStrategy):
        self.drive = drive

    def Drive(self):
        self.drive.drive_strategy()
```